# Basis of Simpson's rule for numeric integration

Tags: calculus, analysis, simpsons-rule

[Exact Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efqi1.png)

Let $f(x) = x^2$, and let *P* denote a partition of [*a*, *b*].

(b) Use the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all partitions *P* with $\Vert P \Vert < \delta$ and any choice of $x^*_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$ $\vert R(f, P, x^*_i) - \frac{b^3-a^3}3 \vert < \epsilon$. Conclude that $\int_a^b x^2 dx = \frac{b^3-a^3}3$.

Upon my first attempt to answer the problem, I was marked wrong and sent for corrections. The advice I was given was to use continuity along with part (a) to answer part (b).

My initial thoughts were to state that $f(x)$ is in fact uniformly continuous over $[a,b]$ and hence is Riemann integrable. Then, using the fact that for any choice of test points of the partition, the Riemann integral is the same, I concluded that $R(f,P) = M(f,P) = L(f,P)$. However, this does not seem to answer the part of the question regarding the *epsilon-delta* proof. I would like to know if my answer suffices, or how I could relate what I have already shown to the part in question. Thank you.

NOTE: This question is related to, but not found in, the book Elementary Classical Analysis, 2nd ed. by Marsden and Hoffman.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: That's what happened: the last three paragraphs were added only after my comment was posted.

Comment: The problem statement would be much more self-contained if it included part (a), with its definitions for $L(f,P),M(f,P),R(f,P)$ as respectively the left endpoint, mid-point, and right endpoint Riemann sums for $f$ over partition $P$.  The conclusion "that $R(f,P) = M(f,P) = L(f,P)$" seems valid only for a constant function $f$, which is not so in this case $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @hardmath What I was trying to get at was the fact that *L(f,P), M(f,P)*, and *R(f,P)* converge to the same value, since $f$ is in fact Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$. While it is not correct that these values are equal, how would I use this fact to show the desired statement?